# google doubleclick studio. video component

Tags: actionscript-3, double-click-advertising, rich-media

im bulding a flash banner where I'm using the components that double-click studio offers for free use in rich media banners.

Im the VideoPlayerAdvanced.
API documentatio here: http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/flash/as3/en/com_google_ads_studio_video_VideoPlayerAdvanced.html

My question is how i dynamically can add a video player like the to the stage by addChild() or something like that. I also want to be able to set the urls for the player to play by code. That part seems quite straight forwards. But i can't figure out how to create an instance of the player dynamically by code.

Anyone that knows this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the component itself to a container movie clip and exported it with a classname for action script.

```
var video:Video = new Video();
addChild(video);
```

"video" holding the component.